# sending back json string with echo problem

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

i use json_encode to send back data from php to jquery through ajax.

and i have noticed that jquery just allow us to use ONE echo in php.

if i use echo json_encode($array);.... and then one more echo json_encode($array2); in the same php file, then it would not work.

or if i use echo json_encode($array); and then another echo "hello"; then it stops working too.

am i correct?

the problem is that when i use

```
$users = mysqli_fetch_assoc($login_user_result);
```

in the ajax called php file together with

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

it doesnt work. it sends the $array correctly but together with a bunch of other code because of the line above it.

but i have to use mysqli_fetch_assoc to get the data from the database.

what is the work around for this?

EDIT: here is the ajax call i used:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "static/js/ajaxcall_login.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:
            {
                username:       $("#login_box .username").val(),
                password:       $("#login_box .password").val()
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data)
            {
                 ................
            }
        )};
```

Comment: what other things are sent together with the JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't see anything wrong with your Ajax Request.

Here is the test code and it worked perfectly...

**Request**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "json.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });

});
```

**Source**:

```
$arr1 = array(3.14, 123, "foo");
$arr2 = array("one", "two", "three");

$arr = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Only one thing to note...

> If you set dataType to **json** in jQuery Ajax Request, the
>   respnse (echo) must be qualified JSON.
>   That is why you can't echo another
>   string along with JSON.

Comment: the problem is when i use $users = mysqli_fetch_assoc($login_user_result); in the php file it echoes back a bunch of code together with the json string. and that makes it stop working. i used firebug to see the data echoed back. so how can i do to use the line above without interferring with jquery json?

Answer (score 1):

> if i use echo json_encode($array);....
>   and then one more echo
>   json_encode($array2); in the
>   same php file, then it would not work.

You need to [merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) the tow arrays before json encod.

> i have noticed that jquery just allow
>   us to use ONE echo in php.

Not true, if you download and check the [jQuery Autocomplete Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) demo, you will see that is used multiple echo inside loop.

Can you show your jQuery code? Seem like you are not defined the data type correctly in your [Ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax) Request. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

JSON has a specific syntax that will become corrupted if you output different values.

For example:

```
$a = array('a', 'b', 'c');
echo json_encode($a);
```

Would give you:

```
(['a','b','c'])
```

...which is interpreted as an array in javascript. If you did

```
$a = array('a', 'b', 'c');
echo json_encode($a);
echo "Hello";
```

then this would be printed out:

```
(['a','b','c'])hello
```

which would cause parsing issues.

To print out two arrays, create a structure that holds both arrays:

```
$a = array();
$b = array();
$c = array('first' => $a, 'second' => $b);
echo json_encode($c);
```

Comment: Where are the parentheses coming from? A JSON encoding of that array would be just `["a","b","c"]` (also, the double quotes...)

Comment: if the phpfile includes a lot of code it is very difficult to not have another echo here and there...

for example is i use $users = mysqli_fetch_assoc($login_user_result); in the same file it echoes a lot of code back to jquery. how do i work around this issue?